# View Control name concatenated with ClientID and masterpage control name in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, master-pages, clientid

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have one master page having one contentplaceholder.
I have one view placed in the contentplaceholder of master page.
I have a few textBoxes that say "name", "age" , "email" in them.
I also have a submit button in my master page.

when I click the submit button, postback event will be called in the controller.

```
//POST
public ActionResult Result(FormCollection Form)
{
}
```

If I try to access the value of the text box `name` using

```
Form["name"]
```

it will give me null value.

Instead

```
Form["$ct100$contentplaceholder1$name"]
```

will give me the correct value.

How can I get the value using only `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't mix Web Forms with MVC

You shouldn't be using `<asp:TextBox id="name" />` but rather

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The input name was autogenerated for you, which you don't want to happen. Try to generate those inputs in MVC-style, like this:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("name")%>
```

or like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
```